# JSF: How to skip validation phase in some cases

Tags: ajax, jsf, bean-validation

if I have the following code inside a form element:

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="dett_cc_appoggio_per_cassa"
    value="#{idfTabDettaglio.idf.ccAppoggio.flagPerCassa}"
    binding="#{submit_dett_cc_appoggio_flag_cassa}"
    disabled="#{ruleCampoAbil.dett_cc_appoggio.protetto}"
    styleClass="idf-radio" converter="javax.faces.Boolean"
    validator="#{idfTabDettaglio.validateFlagCassa}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="${msgs['form.radio.true']}" itemValue="true" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="${msgs['form.radio.false']}" itemValue="false" />
    <f:attribute name="dett_mesi_proroga" value="#{dett_mesi_proroga}" />
    <f:attribute name="dett_gg_preavviso" value="#{dett_gg_preavviso}" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{idfTabDettaglio.onChangeFlagCassa}"
            process="@this"
            update="@this dett_cc_appoggio_abi dett_cc_appoggio_cab dett_cc_appoggio_numero  
                          dett_cc_appoggio_intest dett_cc_appoggio_intest_hid 
                          dett_ape_pratica dett_add_comm dett_periodicita dett_mancata_rest 
                          dett_perc_annua dett_comm_minime dett_note dett_comm_magg_mod  
                          dett_comm_prat_non_std dett_comm_prat_urg" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

I notice that the validator method `validateFlagCassa` will be called both on changing value of radio button and both when pressing the button inside the same *form*.

My question is: Is there a way to skip the call to the method `validateFlagCassa` when I change the value of the  radio button? How to discriminate from whom the method is called?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The title of my question is wrong. I mean that I would like di discriminate in which case I am when I enter inside the `validateFlagCassa` method.

Comment: Do you want to skip validation altogether, or ignore the effect of a failed validation?

Comment: I want to ignore the effect of the process validation when I change the value of the radio button, whereas I want the effect of the process validation to be active when I click on the button of the same form